# Why is Ubuntu caching DNS settings from a previous connection?

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, dns, 16.10, vpn

Recently I have started connecting to a VPN. After some initial problems, I commented out `dns=dnsmasq` from the `NetworkManager`.con and Ubuntu pulled the DNS servers from my VPN connection.

Four days ago; however, I connected to a new Wifi connection and somehow the details are being cached by Ubuntu somewhere.

I have checked that `NetworkManager` starts without issues, that the base and head files don't have anything out of the ordinary in them (one is blank and the head is just the default one), that `dnsmasq` is disabled and that there are no other configuration details which could affect `DNS`. I have restarted `NetworkManager`, checked `bind, nscd, dnsmasq, resolvconf` and there is nowhere any configuration that could affect Ubuntu and impose those DNS settings regardless of Wifi or VPN connection (I have tried two different Wifi connections and two VPNs). None of the connections have any DNS servers attached to them.

I have also stopped and disabled `avahi-daemon`, just in case that could have an impact.

Regardless of what I do, when I boot up the laptop I get the same three name servers (two from a cable company and one from Google).

When I start the VPN, I get the same DNS entries in `resolv.conf`. If I enable `dnsmasq` in the `NetworkManager` config file, `resolv.conf` changes to my loopback address and still doesn't pick up the DNS details from the VPN.

I have even tried upgrading to 16.10 from 16.04 LTS in the hope that it would overwrite some files and restore the normal operation. Nothing has worked.

What else should I do?